# From txt file to 2d double array in JAVA

Tags: java, arrays, file, multidimensional-array

i'm working on my project in JAVA and i have .txt file that contain data like this :

> 3.4413 44.5444 22.793
>   33.3321 222.1333 44.7785
>   23.3001 31.1333 4.7785
>   77.9999 8.0001 -1.3213 3.2311

so how can i read the .txt file and convert it to :

> double[0][0] = {3.4413,44.5444,22.793}
>   double[0][1] = {33.3321 222.1333 44.7785}
>   double[1][0] = {23.3001 31.1333 4.7785}
>   double[1][1] = {77.9999 8.0001 -1.3213 3.2311}

Comment: That looks like 3D to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are sure that you'll be getting only 3 entities in every line then you can do something like this:

```
public static void main (String[] args) 
{
    double[][] arr = new double[10][3];
    int ptr = 0;
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    while(in.hasNext()) {
        arr[ptr][0] = in.nextDouble();
        arr[ptr][1] = in.hasNext() ? in.nextDouble() : 0d;
        arr[ptr++][2] = in.hasNext() ? in.nextDouble() : 0d;
    }
}
```

Please note that here I have used Scanner and am taking input from `System.in`. You can replace it to take input from your file.

Considering the above input this will result in the following output:

```
arr[0][0] -> 3.4413
arr[0][1] -> 44.5444
arr[0][2] -> 22.793
```

For the first row and so on.